# Remove "Integer" properties from JSON Object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

JSON Object:

```
{
   "Footer": "footer",
   "RowType": 4,
   "answers": [
      {
         "answer": 1,
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter"
      },
      {
         "answer": 2,
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to remove all `"integer"` properties from JSON. **JSON object may differ every time**. So, consider that we do not know property key names.

Expected JSON Object:

```
{
   "Footer": "",
   "answers": [
      {
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter"
      },
      {
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter2"
      }
   ]
}
```

The above JSON object is just an example. JSON objects may differ every time (the user uploads JSON objects from UI) and I don't know the hierarchy and key/property names in JSON in advance. And JSON may contain N-nested properties.

I tried a lot things, but couldn't achieve the solution. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What had you tried already? Where did you failed?

Comment: You want to ignore **integer** types during serialization of your string? I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: If the json is serialized from one of your types you can go to that type and mark the property to be not serialized

Comment: I think there are a couple of ways to do this.

Firstly you could deserialize the json and then use reflection to identify properties on the object that are integers - then project what you want into a new anonymous type....but this is likely to affect performance and will be a bit hacky.

My other suggestion would be to take the json string and use a regular expression to identify and remove the properties.

I'll put something together and submit a proper answer.

Comment: @RahulSharma and D.J. I did not serialized them, JSON objects are uploaded from UI, and they may differ every time(as I mentioned in the question), and I need to remove all properties that has "integer" values. That's why I posted the question

Comment: @D.J. JSON Objects are uploaded from UI, and I don't know the hierarchy and key/property names in JSON. So, I need to detect "integer" value properties and remove them from ANY JSON Object

Comment: @WayneFeltham liked your approach, I will try to solve with regex.

Comment: @ikram - your question got re-opened, so you could now [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json =
        @"{
           ""Footer"": ""footer"",
                ""RowType"": 4,
                ""answers"": 
                [
                    {
                        ""answer"": 1,
                        ""FooterInner"": ""innerfooter""
                    },
                    {
                        ""answer"": 2,
                        ""FooterInner"": ""innerfooter2""
                    }
                ]
            }";
    JToken nodeList = JToken.Parse(json);
    List<JTokenType> typesToRemove = new List<JTokenType>(){JTokenType.Boolean, JTokenType.Float, JTokenType.Integer};

    removeFields(nodeList, typesToRemove);

    Console.WriteLine(nodeList.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void removeFields(JToken token, List<JTokenType> typesToRemove)
{
    JContainer container = token as JContainer;
    if (container == null) return;

    List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
    foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
    {
        JProperty p = el as JProperty;
        if (p != null && typesToRemove.Contains(p.Value.Type))
        {
            removeList.Add(el);
        }

        removeFields(el, typesToRemove);
    }

    foreach (JToken el in removeList)
    {
        el.Remove();
    }
}
```

I am just sharing my first working code, and also for extension method solution you can use @Anu Visman's answer(I didn't try it).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adjust (and CHECK) the RegEx for your needs but this method will strip out the integers from the json string.

```
        private string CleanJson(string json)
        {
            var regEx = new Regex("(\"\\w*\": \\d*,)");
            var jsonWithoutIntegers = regEx.Replace(json, string.Empty);

            return jsonWithoutIntegers;
        }
```

Comment: This is only intended as a guiding example.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Nothing changed. But I liked the idea, I will try to make some modifications on your example, thanks

Comment: Nothing changed probably because the regex isn't quite right - I only threw this together as a quick test and it worked for me.

Just adjust the regex.

Comment: With regex it did not work, because unnecessary ','(comma) '(' ')'(parenthesis) and other signs left in json after replacing. I found another way, and shared in question detail, thank you for your help.

Comment: I still think the regEx method would perform better if you could work out what the pattern needed to be.  Either way though, I'm glad you got it working  :)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way may be writing it up as an extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static JToken RemoveFieldTypes(this JToken token,params JTokenType []fieldTypes)
    {
        JContainer container = token as JContainer;
        if (container == null) return token;

        var tokensToRemove = new List<JToken>();
        foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
        {
            JProperty p = el as JProperty;
            if(p!=null && fieldTypes.Contains(p.Value.Type))
            {
                tokensToRemove.Add(el);
            }
            el.RemoveFieldTypes(fieldTypes);
        }
        foreach (JToken el in tokensToRemove)
        {
            el.Remove();
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Now you can do the following.

```
JToken nodeList = JToken.Parse(strJson);
nodeList.RemoveFieldTypes(JTokenType.Integer);
```